# why two inline-block elements are in the separate line while they should be in same line?

Tags: html, css

I have two `a` tags and I set their `display`s to `inline-block` while I expect them to be on the same line but they are on the different lines, so this is happening?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <a href="" style="display:inline-block">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
 elit. Magnam, quam.
    Inventore nihil, quod eos
    porro neque sed ducimus ipsam soluta maiores et maxime harum dolorum unde culpa cupiditate 
 sapiente quia
    quaerat omnis laboriosam, doloribus est.</a>
<a href="" style="display:inline-block">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
elit. Magnam, quam.
    Inventore nihil, quod eos
    porro neque sed ducimus ipsam soluta maiores et maxime harum dolorum unde culpa cupiditate 
sapiente quia
    quaerat omnis laboriosam, doloribus est.</a>
</body>

</html>
```

output:

[image]

expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of an `inline-block` is determined by its `width` property which (in this case) is the default for `a` elements: `auto`.

For an `inline-block`, `auto` means it is as wide as it needs to be to hold its content unless constrained by its container.

Each element has a *lot* of text in it, so it is as wide as its container; consequently the second element word wraps to the next line.

---

If you want to lay out elements in a row, look to [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) or [Grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) instead.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <a>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
 elit. Magnam, quam.
    Inventore nihil, quod eos
    porro neque sed ducimus ipsam soluta maiores et maxime harum dolorum unde culpa cupiditate 
 sapiente quia
    quaerat omnis laboriosam, doloribus est.</a>
  <a>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
elit. Magnam, quam.
    Inventore nihil, quod eos
    porro neque sed ducimus ipsam soluta maiores et maxime harum dolorum unde culpa cupiditate 
sapiente quia
    quaerat omnis laboriosam, doloribus est.</a>

</div>
```

---

If you want to have the sentences run on from each other (which I *think* your low resolution picture is trying to express) then you want `display: inline` (the default). Where the individual [fragments](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-4/#fragmentation) will wrap independently of the entire element.

```html
<div class="container">

  <a>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
 elit. Magnam, quam.
    Inventore nihil, quod eos
    porro neque sed ducimus ipsam soluta maiores et maxime harum dolorum unde culpa cupiditate 
 sapiente quia
    quaerat omnis laboriosam, doloribus est.</a>
  <a>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
elit. Magnam, quam.
    Inventore nihil, quod eos
    porro neque sed ducimus ipsam soluta maiores et maxime harum dolorum unde culpa cupiditate 
sapiente quia
    quaerat omnis laboriosam, doloribus est.</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Getting Expected Output You should remove the

**display:inline-block**

from both anchor tags and then apply

**display:flex**

on body tag this will make both anchor tag in the same line.

You can also get the expected output by only removing this display:inline-block property.